# Blog module for Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore

I want to create blog so i am finding blog module in sitecore.I found the link of WeBlog [here](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/WeBlog.aspx) but it is not available for Sitecore 8. Is there any module available for blog in Sitecore 8?

Comment: Read this https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/7/t/99 and try

Comment: Well this is a valid question,why people just keep discouraging to ask question?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at XBlog? It is another blog module offerring in the Sitecore Marketplace. https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/XBlog.aspx